# Benchmarking Couchbase with 'YCSB'

Tags: couchbase, ycsb

I am benchmarking with YCSB's Couchbase client.
The client fails to complete the defined operations number against the db. I never manage to reach the 'recordcount=30000000'.    Where can I find the log dir of that client?

Answer (score 0):

By default, YCSB logs to STDOUT and only at the INFO level. This also includes errors, so they should be visible in the shell where you are executing the query. You can either pipe your shell to a logfile (via the `>` operator) or configure YCSB to use a different logging mechanism in the first place.

We are happy to work with you to fix the problem, but without actual error logs this might not be possible. Note that for more extended back-and-forth I recommend you the [couchbase forums](https://forums.couchbase.com/) where a back and forth to iterate on your problem is a more suited style instead of a single shot answer. Alternatively if you provide more information in your original post, I can edit my answer too.